# SQL Pivot, rows to columns

Tags: sql, pivot

I've tried to find out how to do this, but all examples are based on a sum.  I don't want to do that.  I have two columns, transaction ID and ProductID.

I really would like the productID returned in columns, with each row being a new transactionID.  There's no sums, involved.

Regards,

Comment: Hi @user3311356, welcome to SO. Please show us your code

Comment: SQL has many flavors, is there a specific DB you wish the answer to work on?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: a few aggregates can work in place of SUM()..  Try using MIN() or MAX()

Answer (score 0):

I have created table with the name of `Products` in which I have two columns as you expected but you can normalize it:

The following script work for `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2`.

**Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
    ProductID INT,
    TransactionID INT
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
INSERT INTO Products VALUES(1,101);
INSERT INTO Products VALUES(2,102);
INSERT INTO Products VALUES(3,103);
INSERT INTO Products VALUES(4,104);
INSERT INTO Products VALUES(4,104);
```

**Note**: The last record insert with the `productID = 4` is twice to just show you the count in the pivot table.

**Getting ProductID's**: Here I am getting `productIDs` by using `STUFF`.

```
select  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ProductID) 
              FROM products 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'');
```

**Pivot table script**:

```
SELECT TransactionID,[1],[2],[3],[4] FROM 
(
    SELECT ProductID,TransactionID,TransactionID   as tr
    FROM Products
) AS a
PIVOT 
(
     count(Tr)
     FOR ProductID in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) AS pvt;
```

**Output**:

```
TransactioID    1   2   3   4
-------------------------------
101             1   0   0   0
102             0   1   0   0
103             0   0   1   0
104             0   0   0   2
```